# MVC 6 Catch-All route with ui.router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, asp.net-core-mvc

Im testing a new AspNetCore MVC 6 setup and i have some issues with a catch-all route. The server is setup to use "http://localhost:5000/" and a catch-all route. Going to "http://localhost:5000/asdasd" works fine, but "http://localhost:5000/asdasd/" fails with an error.

Setting the base href in _layout.cshtml:
    `<script>
        document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>`

Using this in my startup:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "catchall",
                template: "{*url}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

and this in my routing.ts:

```
module app {
export class RoutingConfig {
    static $inject = ["$locationProvider", "$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider"];
    private ViewLocation: string = "assets/views/";

    constructor(private $locationProvider: ng.ILocationProvider,
        private $stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider,
        private $urlRouterProvider: ng.ui.IUrlRouterProvider
    ) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $stateProvider.state("home", <ng.ui.IState>{
            cache: false,
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: this.ViewLocation + "home/home.html",
            controller: HomeController.ControllerId,
            controllerAs: "vm"
        });
    }
}

angular.module("app").config(RoutingConfig);
}
```

Comment: In general, a catch-all route should be registered at the end as that's the final one you want to run after all other routes are run through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot repro what you are seeing after fixing up the routes like below:

**Routes:**

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "catchall",
                template: "{*url}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "CatchAll" });
        });
```

Action:

```
public string CatchAll(string url)
{
    return $"CatchAll:{url}";
}
```